# Nvarchar perform better than varchar?

Tags: sql-server, performance, varchar, nvarchar

I am really surprisde to see that in my MS SQL table, I am defining a field `varchar` and doing group by with another table's field.

When I do the same thing with the column as `nvarchar` it is 3 second faster than `varchar`
when, theoretically, varchar should be faster because of 1 byte char.

Can anyone explain me why `nvarchar` is faster in this instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply the query plan and statistics? Chances are that changing the type resulted in new statistics being generated and these result in a better plan.

Comment: nvarchar is certainly not faster. @Keith's explanation sounds likely.

Comment: @Shuvra: what if you change the type *back* to 'varchar'? If it's the statistics, you should now have better performance than first.

Comment: how can i see query plan and statistics?

Comment: Is there a join/comparison with another nvarchar column? The conversion is expensive, so converting from varchar to nvarchar may actually improve things.

Comment: very strange, if i use tinyint instead of nvarchar. tinyint is slower more..

Comment: hi keith, please see the query statistics:

Comment: Query Profile Statistics     
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements 12  6  9.0000
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 949872  316624  633248.0000
  Number of SELECT statements  39  14  26.5000
  Rows returned by SELECT statements 119  14  66.5000
  Number of transactions  12  6  9.0000
Network Statistics     
  Number of server roundtrips 6  3  4.5000
  TDS packets sent from client 15  6  10.5000
  TDS packets received from server 73  23  48.0000
  Bytes sent from client 43260  14458  28859.0000
  Bytes received from server 275650  85058  180354.0000

Comment: Time Statistics     
  Client processing time 31  0  15.5000
  Total execution time 20151  15  10083.0000
  Wait time on server replies 20120  15  10067.5000

Comment: Hi keith, Mitch,james, Can you pleas give me your email. I can email the query plan and statistics.. shuvra

Comment: @Shuvra - Please edit your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` definitions of both tables including any indexes they may have so we can see if @James's explanation works.

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems use Unicode internally. I think that makes nvarchar faster since it does not need any converting.

Comment: When you read a varchar the OS needs an encoding conversions. With nvarchar you do not need this.